# PyCrypto import AES issue

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I use AES encryption first time and have that issue, when import AES from `Crypto.Cipher`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gek0n\Desktop\wargames\server.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\Crypto\Cipher\_AES.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\Crypto\Cipher\_AES.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 914, in resource_filename
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1601, in get_resource_filename
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1629, in _extract_resource
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 990, in get_cache_path
AttributeError: ResourceManager instance has no attribute '_warn_unsafe_extraction'
```

Someone said, there is a problem with installer, but I used .exe installer for x64 system.
Someone said, he changed `_warn_unsafe_extractor` to different name and problem was solved, but could not find this file.

Now I have a new error (after reinstalling PyCrypto with PIP)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gek0n\Desktop\wargames\server.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 50, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import _AES
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 не является приложением Win32.
```

I don't know, how to solve this, I'll just describe my actions:

1. pip uninstall pycrypto
2. pip install pycrypto (with error)
3. pip install --upgrade pycrypto (with error)
4. download and start exe for amd64 (link: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml)
5. Try to import - done!

P.S.
Before this actions I try to create the environment using a win32 installation, but it is no help!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows i reinstalled PyCrypto module ( [link](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) ) and all works for me.

Comment: I was having the same DLL load error as mentioned by gek0n on Windows 7 machine. I followed the following steps to resolve the issue: 1. upgraded pip with python -m pip install --upgrade pip, 2. uninstall pycrypt with pip uninstall pycrypto, 3. reinstalled pycrypto

Answer (score -2):

pip uninstall pycrypto
pip install pycrypto (with error)
pip install --upgrade pycrypto (with error)
download and start exe for amd64 (link: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml)
Try to import - done!

Didnt work for me cause am using python 3